# Error while running docker container

Tags: ssh, docker, gerrit

I am running a `docker` image using the following command.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 --rm \  
-e AUTH_TYPE='DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT' \
-v /home/gerrit-site:/home/gerrit/site \
-v /home/nidhi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/id_admin_rsa.pub \
-v /home/nidhi/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_admin_rsa \
-e GERRIT_ADMIN_USER='admin' \
-e GERRIT_ADMIN_EMAIL='admin@fabric8.io' \
-e GERRIT_ADMIN_FULLNAME='Administrator' \
-e GERRIT_ADMIN_PWD='mysecret' \          
-e GERRIT_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY='/home/gerrit/ssh-keys/id_admin_rsa' \
-e GERRIT_PUBLIC_KEYS_PATH='/home/gerrit/ssh-keys' \
-v /home/nidhi/.ssh:/home/gerrit/ssh-keys \
--name gerrit admin_gerrit
```

I know the command is right cause I had used this command before and it worked perfectly fine. But now, when I run this command I get the following error,

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 2c9514c3b0d953344e66525d083c7ec3921cb9cde2185f43ec3bec2579597485: stat /home/nidhi/.ssh/id_rsa: permission denied
```

I checked the permission for the `ssh` public and private keys. The permission is 700 and is owned by nidhi. Please can someone point out what my error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When docker runs, the uid in your container will likely not match the uid on the host. So with a host volume containing files with 700 permissions, that will not be readable by the uid inside the container. Three options come to mind:

1. To keep the 700 permissions and same image, you'd need to chown the file on the host to match the uid inside the container.
2. You can use a named volume instead of a host volume, add your credentials to that named volume, and then set permissions inside there to match the containers where you'll use the volume.
3. Or you can use a different image that's been rebuilt to change the uid to match your own on the host.

Comment: Tried it.. Made a few changes in the dockerfile itself... Works fine :) Thanks!